# How to add Maven dependencies in the classpath of a Debug Configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, dependencies

I am new to Maven and I'm using Eclipse with the m2eclipse plugin. I've created a webapp Maven project. I added several dependencies in my `pom.xml` and the dependencies got resolved. I executed `clean install` on Maven build utility. The source code is correctly compiled.

[image: eclipse screenshot]

But if I want to run or debug the webapp I can't add the amven dependency in the classpath. For example, if I create a new Debug Configuration, I go to the Classpath section but I can't view listed the Maven dependencies in the User entries. If I try to add them by clicking *Advanced*, then *Library*, then *Maven Managed Dependencies* I got the alert "Use Maven Project settings to configure Maven dependency resolution".

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Why do you need to change the classpath for debugging in Eclipse?

Comment: _"Maven Managed Dependencies"_ means the dependencies are dynamically computed by the `pom.xml` file of a project. To add or to remove _"Maven Managed Dependencies"_ you have to edit the `pom.xml` file. You can create another (Maven) project with the dependency to add and use _Add Projects..._ instead of _Advanced..._ or you can add directly the JARs via _Add External JARs_. Please note that additional dependencies can change the program logic during debugging, i. e. the application behaves differently than during normal execution.